# What does the Image SRC not change?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is my test site :

http://hackmeout.net/Test/entireweb.html

I don't know how to change this image :

```
http://media.entireweb.com/images/pages/s2/skins/skin_web_glare.png
```

I checked all my CSS files but still my Image source is "`http://media.entireweb.com/images/pages/s2/skins/skin_web_glare.png`" can anyone tell me where the CSS is leading to.

I KNOW it is skin.css but I do have skin.css on wentireweb.html but still..I'm unable to change the SRC.

Thanks

Comment: What Brad said. Also I cannot find `skin_web_glare.png` in the page source.

Comment: @Mr.Genius - I know that.I don't know how the source is going there..Check out the source.. !! No entireweb anywhere !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image is coming off `.web #front_logo, .web #search_form, .web #search`.  You won't find this in your css file because there is an extra css file included in the head.  That CSS file comes off the server.  Remove that line from your HTML source too.

Comment: So how do i modify it.I want to remove that logo ? Any way you can think of ??

Comment: Override the CSS from another css or change the selector

Answer (score 2):

the image located under the selector `.web #front_logo, .web #search_form, .web #search` in the skin.css file, it has the following format

```
.web #front_logo, .web #search_form, .web #search {
    background-image: url("../skin_web_glare.png");
}
```

is this what you need...or I miss something?

Comment: I do have skin.css in my DB as well but why does it go to entireweb ??

Comment: the css file located at http://media.entireweb.com/images/pages/s2/skins/default/skin.css so when it asks the png file to use it as background image it ask it from http://media.entireweb.com/images/pages/s2/skins directory